# Errors on Compiling my first program on OpenGL on Ubuntu

Tags: opengl

I am trying to run the following program on ubuntu 15.04. However on typing "g++ pgm1.cpp -lglut"
I am getting following errors

**/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc9aXqhZ.o: undefined reference to symbol 'glClear'**

**/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line**

Though I am familiar with C programming in Codeblocks and DevC++, this is the first time I am working on Ubuntu and OpenGL. I installed ubuntu and files related to OpenGL based on information available on the net. The sample program too is from the internet. I would request help in getting the program run. Thanks.

```
# include "GL/freeglut.h"
# include "GL/gl.h"
# include <GL/glut.h>

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
}
void display (void) 
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
}
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutCreateWindow("A Blank Window");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. try update your system. and run `ldconfig`
2. how did you compile your code? what arguments are you using?

Comment: I used following commands: "g++ pgm1.cpp -lglut"

Comment: I tried running ldconfig command. I am getting a message "Cant create temporary cache file/etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied"

Comment: try `sudo ldconfig`. When you see Permission denied. adding sudo to the command will fix that 99% of the time(not the best habit though)

Comment: This isn't really a graphics question, it is more of programming/linker question and the folks over at stack overflow will probably have an answer, I recommend moving the question over there.

Answer (score 4):

You need to link with the OpenGL library. Try adding `-lgl` to the compilation command.

Comment: I did try adding -lgl to the compilation command on seeing this suggestion on one of the internet sites. But it does not help